# Something wrong with C++ standard (or most probably that I don't understand english well)

Tags: c++, c++20, c++23

According to C++ draft standard the implementation of `std::iter_value_t` must be:

> template using iter_value_t = see below ;
>
> Let RI be `remove_cvref_t<I>`. The type `iter_value_t<I>` denotes
>
> (2.1)— `indirectly_readable_traits<RI >::value_type` if `iterator_traits<RI>` names a specialization generated from the primary template, and
>
> (2.2)— `iterator_traits<RI >::value_type` otherwise.

I understand that:

```
type iter_value<T>:  // OK, this is not C++, is to clarify my question
   type R = remove_cvref_t<T>;
   if (iterator_traits<R> is a specialization of iterator_traits)
       return indirectly_readable_traits<R>::value_type;
   else
       return iterator_traits<R>::value_type;
```

But in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iter_t) the implementation must be:

> Computes the `value type` of T. If `std::iterator_traits<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>` is **NOT** specialized, then `std::iter_value_t<T>` is `std::indirectly_readable_traits<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>::value_type`.
> Otherwise, it is `std::iterator_traits<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>::value_type`.

So the code to implement it must be

```
type iter_value<T>:
    type R = remove_cvref_t<T>;
    if (iterator_traits<R> is a specialization of iterator_traits)
         return iterator_traits<R>::value_type;
    else 
        return indirectly_readable_traits<R>::value_type;
```

So, in my understanding, the 2 definitions of `std::iter_value_t` are different. Which one is the correct? (I suppose the second one).

But, as I am not an english speaker, most probably the problem is with my english. So I appreciate if you clarify the meaning.

References: [c++ standard](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2023/n4958.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

Your understanding is flipped.

> if `iterator_traits<RI>` names a specialization generated from the primary template

The primary template is the one that is

```
template< class Iter >
struct iterator_traits;
```

And not

```
template</* possibly params */>
struct iterator_traits</* stuff here */>;
```

There is some confusion with cppreference using the term "**NOT** specialized" to mean "uses the primary template". When you *instantiate* a template, you always get a specialisation, either from the primary template, or a declared specialisation.

Answer (score 2):

> Which one is the correct? (I suppose the second one).

In general, in case of deviations, assume that the standard is correct and that CppReference has either made an incorrect translation (into easier-to-humanly-parse rules) or has not caught up with some changes.

In this case, however, they are saying the same thing.

[[readable.traits]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/readable.traits) reads [**emphasis** mine]:

> Let RI be `remove_cvref_t<I>`. The type `iter_value_t<I>` denotes
>
> - (2.1) `indirectly_readable_traits<RI>​::​value_type` if `iterator_traits<RI>` names a specialization **generated from the
>   primary template**, and
> - (2.2) `iterator_traits<RI>​::​value_type` otherwise.

It is a common misconception that "a specialization" refers to "an explicit partial or full specialization", whereas a specialization is simply a concrete entity where all template parameters are specified. In this case, (2.1) can be paraphrased as

> `indirectly_readable_traits<RI>​::​value_type` if `iterator_traits<RI>` has not been specialized - i.e., we are using the primary template of `iterator_traits` to generate `iterator_traits<RI>`.

Which is similar to the explanation from CppReference.